# Prove all elements $x_n \geq \sqrt{2}.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Given $x_1 = 2,$ and $$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(x_n + \frac{2}{x_n} \bigg),$$ show that for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ $x_n \geq \sqrt{2}.$

I tried the following. Suppose, for contradiction, that $x_{n+1} < \sqrt{2}.$ Then, $$\frac{1}{2}\bigg(x_n + \frac{2}{x_n} \bigg) < \sqrt{2},$$ and $$x_n + \frac{2}{x_n} < 2\sqrt{2}.$$ Given that $x_n \geq \sqrt{2},$ it follows that $$\sqrt{2} + \frac{2}{x_n} \leq x_n + \frac{2}{x_n} < 2\sqrt{2},$$ and $$\sqrt{2} + \frac{2}{x_n} < 2\sqrt{2}.$$ So, $$\frac{2}{x_n} < \sqrt{2},$$ and $$\sqrt{2} < x_n.$$ No contradiction. I've tried proving it directly, by squaring both sides and by leaving the expression as is, and I consistently find that the $x_n$ and the $x_n^{-1}$ are together problematic.

I also tried something that allowed me to arrive at the following: $$x_{n+1}x_n \geq 2.$$ But, I don't think that's helpful.

Help?:)

Comment: Just apply "AM >= GM" to $\frac{1}{2}\bigg(x_n + \frac{2}{x_n} \bigg)$ ...

Comment: AM-GM inequality.

Comment: What is the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: The [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)

Comment: Should I delete my post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is immediate from AM-GM: $\frac{1}{2}\bigg(x + \frac{2}{x} \bigg)$ is the arithmetic mean of $x$ and $2/x$, which is always greater than or equal to the geometric mean $\sqrt{x\cdot\frac{2}{x}}=\sqrt{2}$ (for $x>0$).

Alternatively, if you don't know AM-GM, you can reach the same conclusion easily with a bit of calculus.  Letting $f(x)=x + \frac{2}{x}$, we have $f'(x)=1-\frac{2}{x^2}$ which is negative for $0<x<\sqrt{2}$ and positive for $x>\sqrt{2}$.  It follows that $f(x)$ is minimized (on $(0,\infty)$) at $x=\sqrt{2}$, so $\frac{1}{2}f(x)\geq\frac{1}{2}f(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

$x_1\geq\sqrt{2}$, $x_2\geq\sqrt{2}$. Now suppose $x_{n-1}\geq\sqrt{2}$, then by AM-GM we have $x_n=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+\frac{2}{x_{n-1}})\geq\frac{1}{2}(2\sqrt{x_{n-1}\frac{2}{x_{n-1}}})=\sqrt{2}$